# Align spans one to each other and center them

Tags: html, css

I want to show a decimal number with currency sign.
The currency and the floating point number should be smaller that the integer part.
For example: `$ 4,080,048.00`
In the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fainick/yrFeB/) you can see the first line is how I want it to be, but it is written in old HTML style.
I done that with modern HTML (The div with 3 spans) but I have a space between the decimal point: `$ 4,080,048. 00`.
How can I make the second line to looks like the first one?

Comment: How is this relevant to html5 and css3

Comment: The HTML should be in HTML5 and CSS3 standart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the markup in a way that there is no space between the spans will fix the problem

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="currency">$</span>
    <span class="integer">4,080.</span><span class="decimal">53</span>
</div>
```

Or, if you don't want to change the markup, you could add `font-size:0;` to your container class

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yrFeB/4/)

```
.container
{
   font-size:0;
}
```

Yet another option would be to add comments between elements within your markup to make it as if the elements were written one after the other:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yrFeB/5/)

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="currency">$</span><!--
    --><span class="integer">4,080.</span><!--
    --><span class="decimal">53</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the white space which is causing this issue

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="currency">$</span>
    <span class="integer">4,080.</span><span class="decimal">53</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrFeB/2/

**I cannot add the comment in the answer above but you shouldn't use `float: left;` for this purpose**