# Table Spacing in WordPress

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table on a WordPress page and I can't seem to remove the white space between rows. Also, I'd like all cells to have a single pixel space so that all of the images in the table are separated by a single pixel.

http://audreyclairecook.com/new/bios

I've tried everything to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tr
{
 font-size:0; /* remove space between rows */
}
td
{
 padding-right: 1px; /* add 1px right padding between imgs */
}
```

Regarding the space between the rows - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906660/703717) for alternate solutions

Comment: The font-size seemed to fix the gap for desktops but mobile devices are still showing a gap between rows.

Comment: @Jeremy did you try the other solutions which I suggested in the post which I linked to ... such as placing html comments between elements?